# How to Combine multiple column in a table and create separate Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

How to Combine multiple column in a table and create separate Column in SQL and insert a single pipe '|' between the data even though some column has empty field.

I have tried using concat but got multiple pipe if there is empty field

```
  select top 4 concat(code2_1,'|',code2_2,'|',Code2_3,'|',code2_4) from 
  Sourcesql
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3qjg.png)

above is a table

for example 4 th row i need PT01|PT02|PT04

I didnt get the answer even i find like below query then how can my above query is duplicate

```
   SELECT 
STUFF(
 COALESCE('|' + code2_1, '') +COALESCE('|' +code2_2, '') +COALESCE('|'+ 
code2_3, '') +COALESCE('|'+ code2_4, ''),
1, 0, '') AS bar
 FROM Sourcesql
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: MS SQL .. own working database

Comment: I think the highest voted answer in the duplicate link covers your question exactly.

Comment: i agree your statement but what if some one using old version of sql then concat_ws doesnot work , please get me compatible answer

Comment: Check the highly voted answer in the duplicate link.  If I were to answer, I would just be paraphrasing it.